# Spark connect to local Hive and not to remote

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I'm using Spring Framework to create an api to query some of my tables in Hadoop. The command I use :

```
  println("-----------------------------------------------------------------before )
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("API")
  .master("local[*])
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
  println("--------------------------------------------------------------------Session was created")
```

I'm using Spark 2.11.6 and Scala v2.2.0. When I use the spark-shell I connect to the remote cluster.

In the log I don't get any errors but I see that a local hive repository is created :

```
     [           main] o.a.h.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql  : Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
    main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created local directory: C:/Users/..../.../Local/Temp/..._resources
    2018-05-10 16:32:32.556  INFO 16148 --- [           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/myuser/....
```

I'm trying to connect to a remote Cloudera cluster. I copied the xml files (hive-site,hdfs-site,core-stire,yarn-site) to the conf directory in my project, to $SPARK_CONF dir. I added the SPARK_HOME path to the PATH variable and I assigned the HADDOP_HOME variable to point to the winutils location.

What else can I do?

The log is pretty long, a few messages that I see and might imply anything to you :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------ENV=local[*]
   2018-05-10 16:32:16.930  WARN 16148 --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 [           main] org.apache.spark.util.Utils              : Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
 main] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@13ee97af{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[           main] org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI              : Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:4040
[           main] o.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState  : URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory failed to set FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory
[           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
[           main] DataNucleus.Datastore                    : The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
[           main] DataNucleus.Query                        : Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
[           main] o.a.h.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql  : Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
[           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore    : Failed to 
      get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
[           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created local directory: C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/1fa7a82b-fe17-4795-8973-212010634cd1_resources
[           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/myuser/1fa7a82b-fe17-4795-8973-212010634cd1
[           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created local directory: C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/myuser/fileasdasdsa
 [           main] o.a.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState  : Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/myuser/asdsadsa/_tmp_space.db
[           main] o.a.s.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl     : Warehouse location for Hive client (version 1.2.1) is file:/C:/Users/myuser/SpringScalaAPI/spark-warehouse
 [           main] o.a.s.s.e.s.s.StateStoreCoordinatorRef   : Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
--------------------------------------------------------------------Session was created
```

To be honest it isn't the first time I handle this type of error. Last time I used play framework. What are the exact steps that needed to do in this case? What variables should really be configured and what variables aren't important?

Comment: this is for sure wrong `.master("local[*])`

Comment: Why you think it wrong ? I used the same piece of code in play framework and it worked..

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ it's first paragraph with example in getting started.

Answer (score 1):

With Spark 2 you can try something like this,

```
val ss = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName(" Hive example")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

Note the `hive.metastore.uris` property, change localhost to point to you sandbox or cluster.

one `ss` is initialized, you can read tables like below,

```
val df = ss.read.table("db_name.table_name")
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to use the xml files from my cluster and not configure the server manualy. Any other idea?

Comment: @JeyJ I am facing similar issue. Any solution to this?

Comment: @AvikAggarwal you can add them you your hadoop conf. get hadoop conf from spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration